# Xcode Won't Parse Files to Find Errors

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a strange issue that I haven't seen or read about anywhere else. My Xcode no longer parses all of my files to find issues/errors. It will display any issues or errors in a file I am currently viewing, and these will persist thereafter, but with 400+ files I can't reasonably visit each one to make it compile. Xcode can build successfully if the code is valid, however I can never know when that is, since I see no errors. Indexing occurs, but no compiling takes place.

Also, when building, the status bar states that Xcode is compiling x out of however many total compile sources but the total number is usually not even close to the actual total number. For example it may say compiling x out of 40 files when there are actually 400 compile sources.

I wasn't doing anything out of the ordinary from my usual tasks when this issue began. New projects will compile, then randomly stop compiling after a period of time.

Things I have tried:

- nuking derived data
- quitting Xcode/restarting computer
- Recloning the project from a known working repository. It will build but won't find errors/issues when they do exist. There should be at least a handful of minor issues but none appear.
- Reinstalling Xcode (4.5.2)
- tried both GCC 4.2 and LLVM 4.1 compilers

Has anyone experienced this issue before and found a solution? This problem has made my job extremely difficult and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to delete the "associated data" or whatever it's called for the app.  It's something you do through Organizer, IIRC.  (Don't have a Mac here to check.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does sound like corruption of DerivedData.  Try this:

1. Clean your target: cmd+shift+K or Product->Clean
2. Quit xcode
3. Delete the contents of /Users/your_user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
4. Restart xcode

(It's safe to delete this folder's contents.  But if you're nervous about that, back it up first).

You should be good to go.

Comment: This worked thank you very much! Deleting the derived data folder by hand was something I had not yet tried